# wp_ob_end_flush_all and wp_suspend_cache_addition()

Tags: php, fatal-error

Im getting these two errors and my site is stuck keeps giving me a 500 error.

The 2 errors are :

```
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid 
callback, function 'wp_ob_end_flush_all' not found or invalid function name in 
/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286


PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_suspend_cache_addition() in 
/public_html/wp-includes/cache.php on line 402
```

Weird note: I accidentally moved all the files into a subdirectory ie. /public_html/examplefolder/allwordpressfiles. and the site worked (without any of the images or links working obviously) but it didn't return a 500 error.

So is there something wrong with my public_html folder I check permissions and they were 755.

Comment: hmmm have you modified WP Core? Or included Core files from inside a theme/plugin?

Comment: It might have been modified. The site was built prior to me working on it. But I have updated the wp core and the site seemed to still work. What is weirding me out I have ran a full back up to when the site was working and still getting the same errors.

Comment: a stack trace would be the most helpful thing for you right now, allowing us to identify what is calling those functions, but specifically, focus on the cause of the warning, something somewhere is trying to use `add_action` or `add_filter` with `wp_ob_end_flush_all` as the second parameter. You must find that code